# Parsing windows command results with Python and regex

Tags: python, regex, windows

I am using the following code to ping a website to check for connectivity. How can I parse the results back to get "Lost = " to see how many were lost?

```
def pingTest():
    host = "www.wired.com"
    ping = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ping","-n","4",host],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )

    out,error = ping.communicate()
    print out
```

This is the return I get from out

```
Pinging wired.com [173.223.232.42] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 173.223.232.42: bytes=32 time=54ms TTL=51
Reply from 173.223.232.42: bytes=32 time=54ms TTL=51
Reply from 173.223.232.42: bytes=32 time=54ms TTL=51
Reply from 173.223.232.42: bytes=32 time=54ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for 173.223.232.42:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 54ms, Maximum = 54ms, Average = 54ms
```

Comment: How about if you also post just what string you get from 'out', since you have gone so far as to print it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step 1: Construct a regular expression that will match `Lost = 0 (0% loss)`, using `\d` tags to substitute for the numeric values, which will vary. Use capturing groups to preserve these values.

Step 2: Use re.search to scan the `out` string.

Step 3: Extract the values from the re's capturing groups.

Comment: Give a man a regex, and he will parse for a day. Teach a man to regex, and he'll parse for a lifetime! Good answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
lost = out.split('Lost = ')[1].split(',')[0]
```

If you do this with your example, lost would contain 0 (0% loss)

If you want just the total you can do

```
lostTotal = out.split('Lost = ')[1].split(' ')[0]
```

If you want the percentage you can do

```
lostPercent = out.split('%')[0].split('(')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
lost = int(re.findall(r"Lost = (\d+)", out)[0])
```

This applies a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to capture the number that comes after "Lost =" and converts it to an integer.